# How to navigate using collectionView in UIViewController- While selecting cell it is going to random view controller not defined one

Tags: iphone, ios, navigation, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

**Hello**,

I made this app using `UITableViewController` later by using buttons in `UIViewController`.

In `UIViewController`*(using buttons)*-the resolution either suits for `iphone4s` and below or `iphone 5` and above..

[image]

To Overcome from this resolution issue I'm making this by inheriting collection view in Existing `UIViewController`...(And I embedded this to `UINavigationController` to navigate)

Everything works fine till displaying...**Problem occurs when I** **select any cell**, It then goes to random view controller.

I used this method

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
int cellNum = [indexPath row]+1;
switch (cellNum) {
    case 1:
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueNew" sender:nil];
    }
        break;
   //---So On----

   }
```

With tableview I did the similar thing, It worked then..

If you need any further information then please leave a comment.

I really googled a lot about this but didn't find any solution. 
So, Please help me on this or If you find any link please share.

**Thank you.**

Answer (score 0):

It was an extremely silly mistake...I picked the wrong method..

I had to use this method instead of above one..

```
  -(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {

 }
```